# Integral with equal bounds

Tags: real-analysis, integration, limits, definite-integrals

While reading Rudin’s “Principles of Mathematical Analysis” Chapter 6 on integration I noticed that there is no mention of the value of something like:

$$\int_a^a f(t)d\alpha(t)$$

I have always considered this integral to be 0, however, thinking better about it, such a conclusion can not follow from the theory of integration so far presented in Rudin since the lower and upper bounds are always taken to be one less than the other.

Therefore, I would like to ask if we need to introduce a convention to state the above or if there is a reasonable justification for it (e.g. taking the limit of one bound approaching the other the integral becomes arbitrarily small).

As always, any comment or answer is welcome and let me know if I can explain myself clearer.

Comment: In fact it's trivial from the definition of the integral that $\int_a^0$.

Comment: Note that the OP is talking about the Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_a^a f(t)\;d\alpha(t)$.  Advice in reading Rudin: do not use any fact until it has been mentioned in the book.  In particular, if $\int_a^a f(t)\;d\alpha(t)$ has not yet been mentioned, don't use it.

Comment: @GEdgar thank you very much for the advice!